# R plotly duplicated values as text in add_sf for customised maps

Tags: r, plotly, maps, polygon, r-sf

I am plotting customised maps with plotly using add_sf with a sf object. Here is the structure of the sf object (CdE_Aff2), with 53 polygons (or observations). I do not know how to produce a "fake" example of this data type, so here is an overview of what I get :

[image: sf object]

I want to color the map with the categorial column "cat" and to display the real value "Ptot" as printed text (hovertext). I am using the following code :

```
Colors <- c("<0.5 mm"="#ffffff", "0.5-2 mm"="#E3AC20", "2-4 mm"="#E3C220", "4-6 mm"="#D2CD20", "6-8 mm"="#C2D820", "8-10 mm"="#8CC217", 
          "10-15 mm"="#07B759", "15-20 mm"="#079C63", "20-30 mm"="#0B8C82", "30-40 mm"="#0F82AC", "40-50 mm"="#206DAC", "50-60 mm"="#0F29C2", 
          "60-80 mm"="#072997", ">80 mm"="#C21797")


p <- plot_ly(stroke=I("black")) %>% 
      add_sf(data=CdE_Aff2, color=I("white"), hoverinfo = "none", showlegend=F) %>%
      add_sf(data=CdE_Aff2, color = ~factor(cat, levels=rev(Classes)), colors = Colors,
             text=~Ptot, hoverinfo = "text", hoveron = "fills")
```

I am using "add_sf" twice because I want the polygon contour to stay even if I remove some categories through the legend. Two issues :

1. The "Ptot" value is displayed multiple times, and not only once. On the figure, I want only one "10.17" when the mouse is on the associated polygon :

[image]

If I use

```
 text=~unique(Ptot)
```

I get the followong error message :

```
Error:
! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
* Size 44: Column `text`.
* Size 73979: Columns `x`, `y`, `color`, and `.plotlyGroupIndex`.
i Only values of size one are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

2. Second question, is it possible to display the entire legend with all categories, even if they do not appear in the data ? I have 14 categories but only 7 are displayed as I only have 7 categories in CdE_Aff2.

Thanks for help

UPDATE with Kat's answer :

I had to remove the first add_sf, which is not convinient as polygons are totally removed if I want to remove a category in the legend and it produces values from all the polygons around (and one NA) :

### [image: Kat suggestion]

Found it with leaflet :

```
pal <- colorFactor(
  palette = as.character(Colors),
  domain = names(Colors)
)

p <- leaflet(CdE_Aff2) %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(cat), color="black", weight=2, opacity=1,
          label=~paste0(CODE, " : ", cat))
p
```

Result :
[image: leaflet solution]

Answer (score 0):

##### Yet another update

When I saw your latest comment, I went back to the data to figure it out. You're right, of course.

What's happening is not multiple values for a specific polygon, but every value in that legend group. This modification adds the argument `split`, which creates the data you want in each tooltip.

Unfortunately, using `split` also modifies the legend. To address this, I've used the argument `legendgroup`, to group like-colored items together and created a new `fixIt` function. The function will change the visibility to `TRUE` for one trace per legend group, remove the element assigned to `split` from the legend (`CODE`) and reorder the traces to maintain the appropriate legend order.

```
library(plotly)

Colors <- c("<0.5 mm"="#ffffff", "0.5-2 mm"="#E3AC20", "2-4 mm"="#E3C220",
            "4-6 mm"="#D2CD20", "6-8 mm"="#C2D820", "8-10 mm"="#8CC217", 
            "10-15 mm"="#07B759", "15-20 mm"="#079C63", "20-30 mm"="#0B8C82",
            "30-40 mm"="#0F82AC", "40-50 mm"="#206DAC", "50-60 mm"="#0F29C2", 
            "60-80 mm"="#072997", ">80 mm"="#C21797")


(p <- plot_ly(stroke=I("black")) %>% 
  add_sf(data=CdE_Aff2, color=I("white"),  hoverinfo = "none", showlegend = F) %>%
  add_sf(data=CdE_Aff2, color = ~factor(cat),  # color = ~factor(cat, levels=rev(Classes)), 
         colors = Colors, split = ~CODE, legendgroup = ~factor(cat), showlegend = F,
         text = ~Ptot, hoverinfo = "text", hoveron = "fills"))

fixIt <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)
  tellMe <- tm2 <- levels(CdE_Aff2$cat)            # all possible legend entries
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$data), function(j) {
    lg <- plt$x$data[[j]]$legendgroup                      # current legendgroup
    if(any(tellMe %in% lg)) {                          # if first occur of group
      plt$x$data[[j]]$showlegend <<- T                          # show in legend
      plt$x$data[[j]]$name <<- lg                         # rem CODE from legend
      tellMe <<- tellMe[!tellMe %in% lg]             # rem legendgroup from list
      aft <- which(tm2 %in% lg)               # reorder to maintain legend order
      plt$x$data <<- append(plt$x$data[-j], plt$x$data[j], after = aft + 1) 
    } 
  })
  plt    # show the plot
}

p %>% fixIt()
```

[image]

---

---

##### *previous answer below*

##### Updated using your actual data

There is more than one unique value per tooltip in `Ptot`—that's why you're seeing what you're seeing.

I didn't have `Classes` in `color = ~factor(cat, levels=rev(Classes))`, so when I tested this I used `color = ~factor(cat)`. Therefore, the colors you see won't match what you've got, but that shouldn't matter, in terms of the fix. (You'll see the original code for `color` is commented out in my code.)

If you wanted to only show unique values this will work. Before and a couple of after shots:

[image]

[image] [image]

Included is a function for modifying the plot (`fixer()`), and how to add this to your plot (`%>% fixer()`).

```
library(plotly)

(p <- plot_ly(stroke=I("black")) %>% 
  add_sf(data=CdE_Aff2, color=I("white"), hoverinfo = "none", showlegend=F) %>%
  add_sf(data=CdE_Aff2, color = ~factor(cat),  # color = ~factor(cat, levels=rev(Classes)), 
         colors = Colors,
         text=~Ptot, hoverinfo = "text", hoveron = "fills"))

fixer <- function(plt) {
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)
  lapply(1:length(plt$x$data), function(j) {
    # split so replacements and unique decipherable
    if(any("text" %in% plt$x$data[[j]]$hoverinfo)) {
      message("none not detected for ", j)
      txt <- plt$x$data[[j]]$text %>% strsplit(., split = "\n") %>% 
        unlist() %>% unique()                 # remove repeated values
      plt$x$data[[j]]$text <<- txt            # replace hover content
    }
  })
  plt                                         # return modified plot
}
p %>% fixer()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! The function gives something if I only keep the second add_sf() that produces the colored polygons, but if I keep the two add_sf, as in my example, it produces an error "Error in strsplit(., split = "\n") : non-character argument". Second, it does not keep only one value, but the value of the polygon + the values from the polygons around... maybe because there are some geometrics in common ? I've updated my initial post with the result

Comment: Hmm, let me think about this. I don't have your data, so it's difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Do me a favor and put `fixer()` between the two `add_sf()`, if that doesn't work, change the order of your two `add_sf()`, but keep `fixer()` in the middle and run it again. Let me know what you see. Even if it doesn't work out right, it will give me a better idea of how I could reproduce the issue.

Comment: If I put add_fixer() between the two add_sd() I have the same error. If I revert the two add_sf(), no data is displayed when the mouse goes over the polygons. I don't know if it is allowed but I putted my RData CdE_Aff2 on this link : https://fromsmash.com/Gc.s1feZnQ-ft

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response. I was out of town, but I really thought I would have had time to look at this while out. Let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: Hello Kat ! Thanks for trying and having a look, that looks so complicated whereas ggplotly manage everything fine.... As on your example, I still have several values displayed : the one for the polygon, and the ones from the polygons around. For example, on your figure on the left, it displays : 8.2, NA, 8.8, and I only want to keep the 8.2 which is the value from the polygon in question...

Comment: I've finally understood what I think you've been trying to tell me all along. (Sorry I'm a bit slow sometimes...) I've updated my answer with a fix that actually should address the issue you're looking to address.

Comment: Hello Kat, I've finally managed to do it very simply with leaflet... I've updated my first post with this alternative, thanks a lot for your help !